# Window background color for a Progress Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have this code in order to display progress dialog:

```
@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    if(progress == null)
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity2.this, null , null);
    progress.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);
}
```

This is my progressDialog layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/loading" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my main Activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tittle_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="6dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_progress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you see the background color is **white**.

When I click on the button in mainActivity the progress dialog appears, but the background color of the page becomes **gray**.

[image]       -------->     [image]

I want it to be white as default and the progress dialog text as black. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding `<include layout="@layout/progress_bar" />` in main Activity layout.

Then I gave a name to Progress Dialog in progressDialog layout such as `android:id="@+id/progress_bar`.

And then with this code, I hided the dialog:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using drawable file

STEP - 1)

main.xml:(add this to your main.xml):

```
<ProgressBar 
android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01" 
android:layout_width="121dp" 
android:layout_height="15dp" 
android:progress="50"
android:max="100" 
android:secondaryProgress="0"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogressbar" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
/>
```

STEP - 2) 
myprogressbar.xml (save this xml in drawable folder)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="25dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#C0C0C0" android:centerColor="#F8F8FF"
                android:centerY="0.75" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:angle="90" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#6B8E23" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="25dip" />
                <gradient android:startColor="#9ACD32" android:endColor="#FFFF00"
                    android:angle="90" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#6B8E23" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I added an image regarding my prblem. I think your code is not what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/splashprogressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
    android:progressBarStyle="@android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"/>

 </RelativeLayout>



RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.splash_progress, null);
        layout.setBackgroundColor("#336C10".hashCode());
```

## 336c10 is color code...use color code for gray here...

Answer (score 0):

Try in your progressDialog layout to use transparent background for main `LinearLayout` and black color for the `TextView`.

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#00000000">

    <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/loading"
         android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```